Monitoring sub panel energy use with CTs
I am trying to monitor the energy use in a shack with a sub panel that is rented behind our house. The cheapest and easiest way seems to be an AC 100 A digital meter with split core CT. My question comes down to how many sensors I need to monitor the total use of the shack?
The wiring is as such: Two hot feeds (R&B), a neutral (W), and ground (G) come off the house main panel and feed into the sub panel. R & B feed into a 40 A main breaker that supplies the sub panel, W goes to the dedicated neutral bus, G goes to ground bus. There are also three 20 A circuits feed stuff in the shacks.
My question stems from the idea that US residential is single phase, but everything I see on CT installation says I need a CT for both R & B hots (2) OR I need a CT for each circuit in the panel (3). Intuitively, I’d think if single phase is indeed single phase and in pursuit of total power use in the shack, I could use one CT with both R & B feeders passing through. If someone could enlighten me as to which number of CT sensors I need, I’d appreciate it.
Lastly, most of these power meters require some sort of wiring to the panel to power the monitor itself. Most installation videos I saw had wiring through a breaker, but I was also wondering if I could just use the main lug on the hot bus and a spot on the neutral bus. The meter capacity is 100A and the panel itself is controlled by a 40 A breaker. I’m sure my intuition is wrong here on both counts, as circuits made the least intuitive sense to me throughout engineering, so I appreciate your time and attention.

I’d suggest you get a power meter fit for purpose. They’re not too expensive. Measuring just current is inaccurate and not suitable for billing.

While measuring current only is not suitable for billing power, it's an indication, and if most of your loads are good power factor (so resistive, or PF corrected), then it's quite good. Induction motors and old-style electronics may read quite inaccurately, but probably good enough to 'monitor'.
On a 240 V circuit, the current direction in the two hots is opposite. If you want to indicate the total power used, the R and B feeders should enter the CT core from opposite sides, so that the currents sum in the core. This works for  the independent 120 V loads as well.
Powering the monitor should be via a breaker, it is an appliance just like any other. You need to be able to disconnect it, and protect its wiring from over current. 'Just' feeding it from the busbars is extremely dangerous, and a code violation that will invalidate your insurance. Size the breaker to match the wiring to the monitor.

If you want to bill energy use, in the EU you need a MID certified meter. This is a standard that specifies measurement accuracy, along with other things, for example MID meters are not resettable. I don't know if a similar standard exists in the US, but it is likely.
If you just want to monitor power use, then no certification is needed.
Meters measure energy by integrating active power, which is the product of current and voltage, so they need to measure both. The meter also needs a power supply. So it will need to be connected to live and neutral.

I need a CT for both R & B hots

If all your loads are 240V then current will be the same in both live wires in opposite direction. If some of your loads are 120V then it won't, as some of the current will return in the neutral wire. So you need two CTs for current.
You may also need to measure voltage to neutral on both live wires, or simply measure on one and assume the other is the same. This reduces accuracy.
As Neil said your meter is an appliance on its own circuit so it needs a breaker. That said you can probably use another breaker already in the panel.
